# Border onTap in a image

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put a border in the image that i've tapped and remove from the others on a GridView, but i don't know how to do that. 
I've put a Gesture Detecture in the Container that holds the image, and when i click should input the border, but i want that the border from the other images desappear, like a selection.

```
class ImageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImageLessonData imageLessonData;
  final String collection;
  static bool tapped = false;
  static bool other = true;

  ImageTile(this.imageLessonData, this.collection);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Material(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: Firestore.instance.collection("images-lessons").document("images").collection(collection).getDocuments(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(!snapshot.hasData){
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
              }
              else {
                return GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc){
                    return GridView(
                      gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            tapped = true;
                            other = false;
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: tapped || !other ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][0],),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            tapped = false;
                            other = true;
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: !tapped || other ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][1],),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            tapped = true;
                            other = false;
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: tapped || !other ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][2],),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                            tapped = true;
                            other = false;
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: tapped || !other ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][3],),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList() ,);
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you really require `tapped` and `other` both.

Could you try this instead? `tappedGestureDetector` will keep track of current selection.

```
  class ImageTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final ImageLessonData imageLessonData;
  final String collection;
  static int tappedGestureDetector = 0; // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'

  ImageTile(this.imageLessonData, this.collection);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Material(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            future: Firestore.instance.collection("images-lessons").document("images").collection(collection).getDocuments(),
            builder: (context, snapshot){
              if(!snapshot.hasData){
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
              }
              else {
                return GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc){
                    return GridView(
                      gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                               setState(() { tappedGestureDetector = 0; }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: tappedGestureDetector == 0 ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][0],),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                               setState(() { tappedGestureDetector = 1; }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: tappedGestureDetector == 1 ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][1],),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                               setState(() { tappedGestureDetector = 2; }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                          }, 
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: tappedGestureDetector == 2 ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][2],),
                          ),
                        ),
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: (){
                               setState(() { tappedGestureDetector = 3; }); // <-- replaced 'tapped' and 'other'
                          }, 
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(border: tappedGestureDetector == 3 ? Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1.0) : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent,),),
                            child: Image.network(doc.data["imageL"][3],),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }).toList() ,);
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```